# Register form error, Unable to make a POST request

Tags: node.js, forms, express, post, ejs

I'm trying to build a web app with a login and register form. But when registration fails every time I register. here is the post method for register page :

```
app.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
try {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    users.push({
        id: Date.now.toString(),
        name: req.body.name,
        mail: req.body.mail,
        username: req.body.username,
        contact: req.body.contact,
        password: hashedPassword,
    });
    res.redirect('/signin');
} catch{
    res.redirect('/signup');
    console.log("some error occured, try again!!");
}console.log(users);
});
```

this is the snippet of the ejs file's form section

```
<form class="flex flex-wrap -m-2" action="/signup" method="POST">
                    <!-- Email input -->
                    <div class="p-2 w-full">
                        <input class="w-full rounded border border-white text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-700 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Email address" type="email" name="mail" required>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Full Name input -->
                    <div class="p-2 w-full">
                        <input class="w-full rounded border border-white text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-700 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" name="name" required>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Username input -->
                    <div class="p-2 w-full">
                        <input class="w-full rounded border border-white text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-700 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Username" type="text" name="username" required>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Phone Number input -->
                    <div class="p-2 w-full">
                        <input class="w-full rounded border border-white text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-700 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Contact Number" type="text" name="contact">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Password input -->
                    <div class="p-2 w-full">
                        <input class="w-full rounded border border-white text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-700 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" required>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Confirm Password input -->
                    <div class="p-2 w-full">
                        <input class="w-full rounded border border-white text-white focus:outline-none focus:border-red-700 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" name="confirm_password" required>
                    </div>
                    <!-- register Button -->
                    <div class="p-2 w-full">
                        <button class="flex mx-auto text-white bg-black border-0 py-2 px-8 focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-900 rounded text-lg">sign Up</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Every time I run the server, the try block didn't execute.
The structure of the project is as follows :
[image: server.js in the root dir and signup.ejs in /static/signup/signup.ejs]

Comment: What is the error? What exactly are you doing to get such an error? Please show us the error? Also, `Date.now` is a function, so your toString will never be unique (also, please don't use dates as ids).

Comment: I've mentioned, the try block doesn't execute. There is no error in the shell but the code jumps directly to the catch block.

Comment: Please change your catch to `catch(error) { console.log(error); }` and see what it outputs.

Comment: I have already added a log statement that says 'some error occured, pls try again!!'

Comment: and as you've commented for date, it's there just for initial building of the project

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to know what your error is because you're not capturing it.
Write your catch block like this:

```
app.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
try {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
    users.push({
        // Date.now.toString() => "function now() { [native code] }"
        // I think you mean Date.now()
        id: Date.now().toString(),
        name: req.body.name,
        mail: req.body.mail,
        username: req.body.username,
        contact: req.body.contact,
        password: hashedPassword,
    });
    res.redirect('/signin');
} catch (error) {
    res.redirect('/signup');
    console.log(error); // What is output here?
}
});
```